# Have markdown-mode render checkboxes as in GFM

Tags: markdown, markdown-mode, gfm-mode

How can I make this:

```
- [ ] check
- [x] box
```

render checkboxes, like in GFM? I think the output is something like

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled> check
<input type="checkbox" disabled checked> box
```

.

I don't want to use org-mode. I know there is gfm-mode, and I saw this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/fredRos/0e3a845de95ec654538f), which shows how to use pandoc to also get GFM-style markdown. However, none of them seems to support checkboxes, unless I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with [Python Markdown](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/) and [Markdown Checklist](https://github.com/FND/markdown-checklist):

`markdown_py -x toc -x markdown_checklist.extension -x smarty foobar.md > foobar.html`

Comment: As you see, I also wanted to have a TOC. Actually, I am still missing the last piece: CSS styling. Pandoc gives me CSS styling and TOC with `pandoc -c ~/.emacs.d/github-pandoc.css --from markdown_github -t html5 --highlight-style pygments --standalone --smart`, but I found no way to render checkboxes. Python Markdown gives me TOC and checkboxes, but no styling.

Comment: I added a follow-up question here: http://superuser.com/questions/956494/python-markdown-with-css